Не работает телеграм бот⠀
Учусь писать телеграм бот, для своего канала. Однако почему то бот долго отвечает на команды или вообще не отвечает. Код маленький, запускаю пока что на PyCharm.
import telebot
from telebot 
import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Предложить новость')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Поддержка')
    markup.row(btn1, btn2)
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Реклама')
    btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Мы в интернете')
    markup.row(btn3, btn4)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доброе пожаловать!', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

def on_click(message):
    if message.text == "Предложить новость":
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, news)
    elif message.text == "Поддержка":
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sup)

def news(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите текст и ссылку на официальный источник новости')

def sup(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Новое обращение')


bot.infinity_polling()


Трудно сказать, в чём проблема, так как непонятно, что за проблема? Медленно отвечает? Вряд ли это из-за кода, скорее всего проблема в скорости сети машины, где запускается бот

Запускаю в пайчарме, на компе, это не сервер, я просто код запускаю и бот работает, останавливаю бот выключается, мне тоже кажется, что не в коде дело. Может на сервер какой-нибудь выгрузить?
